Как отделить аутентификацию по лицу и по отпечатку пальца в Android?
Я хочу подключить биометрию в свое приложение. У меня есть две иконки:

Иконка разблокировки по лицу
Иконка разблокировки по пальцу

В зависимости от того, какой способ основной на устройстве, нужно ставить нужное изображение на кнопку. Либо же вообще не ставить эту кнопку.
Исопльзую стандартную библиотеку:
androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0

Пытался решить с помошью констант BIOMETRIC_STRONG и BIOMETRIC_WEAK, но они обе включают в себя и разблоикровку по лицу, и разблокировку по отпечатку пальца.
На примере вызывается BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS
when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG)) {
                    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS -> {
                        
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Аутентификация по отпечатку пальца недоступна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }

Может быть есть решение определять тип аутентификация, не связанное с этой библиотекой, но никак не могу придумать.

Нет такой возможности, просто биометрический вход и все. Позже добавят радужку глаза и ничего менять не придется :)
